# How retrieve parent's list of component child in react-native (or react ?)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to retrieve the list of parent compoenent in a component child. I doesn't want pass props cause it coupling componenents.

The purpose of this it's to display an image into an imageFallBack components. The source of image would be depends from parent components. The imageFallBack components it's call from an Image components and image component can be in a view, so i won't past props into tree.

Finally i want imageFallBack component retrieve the list of parents and for each parent check into config file if a source (of fallbackimage) is configured

It's possible, or it's an antipattern ? thanks

Comment: I think you should read about [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: i don't think context is what i need. i doesn't need to share data between compoment, but child compoment can get config compared to parent

Comment: From what you described, it sounds like an antipattern to me. Usually you iterate through a list in your parent component an generate one child component per item in the list There are cases where child and parent share state but that's where the context comes in.